# npm parser "html-to-text" not working in shell script

Tags: node.js, shell, npm

I am trying to extract text from a given directory using `npm HTML-TO-TEXT` parser. over command line i am able to get text but using shell i am not able to get that.
Here is my shell script that i wrote

```
 #!/bin/sh
    for i in `ls -a *.html`
    do
    s=$i
    fname=${s##*/}
    me=${fname%.*}
    text=$me+".txt"
    cat $i |html-to-text  $i >$text
    sed -i.bak '/[*]/ !d' $text 
    sed -i.bak -e 's/*//g' $text
    done
```

Can some one help to correct this shell script.

Comment: this sounds like a lot of code to me. What is the underlying idea here? I am quite sure you can remove half of the commands

Comment: why are you doing `cat $i | html2txt $i > $text`. Surely you're passing the same file twice. `cat` is usually not necessary. So try `html2text "$i" > "$text"` (note that it is good practice to dbl-quote var names (except in rare cases) ) . Good luck.

Comment: And as a zillion other posts here on S.O. will explain, `for f in *.html; do ` should be sufficient. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> over command line i am able to get text but using shell i am not able
>   to get that.

With `sed -i.bak '/[*]/ !d' $text` you delete all lines from `$text` that don't contain a `*`; that's presumably not what you want.